# How to share my google colaboratory along with data from mounted drive?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory, sharefile

I am working on google colaboratory and i have mounted my gdrive to it so i can access the csv data i am processing with pandas for example.

```
# Mount the path to the location of your data
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/gdrive')
```

Everything works great.

But now when i share my colab to other colleagues they have no access to the csv files ofcourse.
So how can i share these csv residing in my drive as well ? Or are there other alternatives to hosting the data into gdrive so i and my colleagues can access them through a panda read_csv ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 easy ways.

### 1. gdown

If you have just 1-2 csv files that can be shared publicly. You can get the file IDs. Then, use `gdown` to download it (no authentication).

Get ID from the shared link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KgSEm4A7hCov2Ta6-CZldqT-9JgtiVRI/view?usp=sharing

```
!gdown --id 1KgSEm4A7hCov2Ta6-CZldqT-9JgtiVRI
```

Your friend will get `dataset.zip` in the current directory.

### 2. kora.drive

If you have many csv files/folders, just put them all in a single folder and share that folder to your friend. I made a library to help download the whole folder. It will check user permission to read that folder, by asking you to authenticate.

Get Folder ID from the folder link

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HvIeNhqtFVllXFWzH5NawDdnIfgGDwCK

```py
!pip install kora -q
from kora import drive

drive.download_folder("1HvIeNhqtFVllXFWzH5NawDdnIfgGDwCK")
```

Your friend will get a new directory `Dataset` inside current directory (e.g. /content/) with all files/subfolders copied from your google drive.

Comment: This looks like it works !! Is there a way to avoid download as sometimes the data can be very huge ? Maybe just access the data just as regular drive.mount(...) would do..

Comment: May be you can split it into groups or sub-folders or zip files, and download each ones.